# How to sign out user automatically after a certain period of time?

Tags: ios, swift

At the Time of Signing In to my Application, I am getting **Time for which the current user login is valid**["liveTime"] from the BackEnd API for a particular user. And I am saving this liveTime(parameter) to the NSUserDefaults.

My requirement is to show the Sign In page again when liveTime will become 0. And If that particular user kills the app and if liveTime is greater than 0, It will show the Default page after Sign In happens.

Please share your experience how to do or what is the best practices to resolve this kind of problems. Please share the code snippets if someone has already done it.

Comment: Make it easier for you creating an expiration date in the future when user logs in using adding the time interval you would like. Then all you need is to check if this date it is past or future and decide what to do based on it

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Use case is like -> if liveTime is equal to 30 days then the user should be signed in for 30 days. if the user signs out before 30 days the liveTime will become 0 and login again , the liveTime again will become 30 days or whatever API is sending at that time for the particular user.This kinda use cases I have to handle also.

Comment: Whenever the user logs in, save the 'liveTime' in NSUserDefaults. Whenever they try to do an action that requires them to be authenticated, check that the liveTime has not been completely elapsed, if the live time has expired, log them out and redirect them to the login page.

Comment: @BobbyW Can you please share the code snippet followed by best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

```
func afterDelay(seconds: Double, closure: () -> ()) {
    let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(when, dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Call the function

```
 self.afterDelay(4) {
                    // Write what you want to happen after 4 sec. You can increase the number
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
```

Comment: @LeoDabus  and Hugo please help me out for the particular use case scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to keep track in **NSUserDefaults** of your *last login timestamp* and the last *maximum live time* retrieved from the server (unless it must be fetched at that moment [thing that would be inappropriate because of the lag that communicating with a server brings]).

Then, in your initial controller's `viewDidLoad` or in your AppDelegate (the choice is yours)check if that time is after the maximum allowed and proceed accordingly.

> **UPDATE:**

Best Practices:

1.- Add some kind of waiting page, to leave the user there waiting until you retrieve that data from the server.

2.- After receiving that Data, check for the timestamp saved in your **NSUserDefaults** and proceed either to **login** or **welcome** pages

3.- If the user logs in, then update the timestamp in **NSUserDefaults**

Comment: Shall I start an alarm manager , after user signs in? or Can you please share the code snippet followed by best practices?

Comment: At the sign in time only I will get this live time. not any other API.